# Unable to locate appropriate constructor Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to run my gradle springboot project for a query which I changed , but I am not able to find what error I am doing. Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong in this.

Here is the new class I created

```
    @Embeddable
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PartsByPartNumber {

    String partNumber;
    
    List<Part> parts;

}
```

And this is the query in my repo class which I have written

```
@Repository
public interface PartRepo
        extends JpaRepository<Part, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Part>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Part> {

......
    @Query("    SELECT new com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.PartsByPartNumber(p.partNumber, p) "
            + " FROM Part p "
            + " GROUP BY p.partNumber ")
    public List<PartsByPartNumber> findByPartsByPartNumber();
}
```

But when I run gradle bootrun I am getting this error

```
2022-08-12 12:16:55 [restartedMain] ERROR o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker.reportError -  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.PartsByPartNumber]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.Part
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.PartsByPartNumber]
2022-08-12 12:16:55 [restartedMain] ERROR o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker.reportError -  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.PartsByPartNumber]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.Part
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.PartsByPartNumber]
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.DetailedSemanticException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.PartsByPartNumber]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.Part
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1245) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2366) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2232) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1503) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:585) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:605) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:714) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) [spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.createQuery(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:142) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:566) [spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Why not use `@AllArgsConstructor` ?

Comment: its all the same..tried that too

Comment: I'm no hibernate expert, but that error says it is looking for a constructor with the signature `public PartsByPartNumber(String partnumber, Part part){}`.  That constructor doesn't exist because there is no field for `Part` in your POJO.  Create a constructor with that signature and I bet you'll see what's happening.

Comment: That is definitely wrong, the types of the entity does not match the query. Do `Part parts;` in the entity (probably is not what you want) or adjust the query, that I am not aware about right now, because there is no @XToY relation annotation. You should show the `Part` class.

Comment: yeah the model I want to query result to map to is String and List<Part> but I dont know why its looking for constructor of a String and Part whereas in the model PartsByPartNumber I have a constructor for String and List<Part>

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation @NoArgsConstructor to the class.

Comment: Have added @NoArgsConstructor but still getting the same error :(

Comment: Why do you have that super() call?

Comment: I have removed the super() call..but still same error

Comment: is partNumber in the entity a String?

Comment: yes its a string

Answer (score 0):

Your class `PartsByPartNumber` has a field `parts` which is of type `List<Part>`, so the created constructor will have the types `String` and `List<Part>`. In the HQL query of your repository you are referring, through the `new com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.PartsByPartNumber(p.partNumber, p)` constructor expression, to a constructor that should be of the type `String` and `Part` though, which simply doesn't exist.

The thing you want to do is AFAIK not directly possible with Spring Data JPA. You need to use Hibernate APIs, e.g. `ResultListTransformer` or fetch a list of `Part` and do the construction and grouping of objects yourself in Java code.

Comment: I was trying to optimize this part as this is taking too long for a million parts Map<String, List<Part>> exPartsByPartNumber = partRepo.findAll().stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Part::getPartNumber)); Any suggestion to optimize this?

Comment: I would rather ask myself if I *really* need to load one million objects, as that is going to cause slowness regardless how you implement it.